# Dynamically menu primefaces 4.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menubar

I'm trying to generate menubar dynamically, i already got that result, but i have a method to check if a  DefaultSubMenu already exist, if the submenu exist it doesn't have to be created and it has to return that submenu, but it keeps generating same submenu when it's found, this is the method

```
 public DefaultSubMenu buildSubMenu(OpcionesMenu opcionPrincipal) throws Exception{
    DefaultSubMenu subMenu=null;

    try {
        if(getMenu()==null){
            DefaultSubMenu newSubmenu=new DefaultSubMenu(opcionPrincipal.getIdOpcionMenu().toString());
            newSubmenu.setId(opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu());

            newSubmenu.setIcon(opcionPrincipal.getIcono());
            newSubmenu.setLabel(opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu());
            subMenu= newSubmenu;
        }else{
            //Checking the list of DefaultSubMenu
            List<MenuElement> opciones=getMenu().getElements();
            boolean validador=false;
            for (MenuElement me : opciones) {

                if(me.getId().equals(opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu())){

                    validador=true;// if it is found
                    subMenu=(DefaultSubMenu)me;
                }
            }
            if(!validador){if not found i create the submenu

                    DefaultSubMenu newSubmenu=new DefaultSubMenu(opcionPrincipal.getIdOpcionMenu().toString());
                    newSubmenu.setId(opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu());
                    newSubmenu.setIcon(opcionPrincipal.getIcono());
                    newSubmenu.setLabel(opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu());
                    subMenu=newSubmenu;
            }
        }
        return subMenu;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Error en la clase UsuarioOpcionMenuController - metodo buildSubMenu\n"
                        + e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }       
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu()` returns the name of menu option and `me.getId()` returns the same thing, you can change the comparation condition:

From:

```
me.getId().equals(opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu())
```

to

```
me.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(opcionPrincipal.getNombreMenu())
```

You are (as i compreend) comparing `Strings` and not objects.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))(description of `equals` method) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) (description of `equalsIgnoreCase` method).

Comment: let me try @Cold, I'll let you know

Comment: Same @Cold, I find the SubMenu, the thing is that i return the submenu that I just found but It seems that it is taken as a new one and I dont want that, I want to add more items in the same SubMenu.... i worked in Primefaces 3.4 tho...

Comment: Ok. Why you dont return the submenu once it's found? You don't need check the validator if you already found what you want right?